# Missing { inserted. \end{align*}

Tags: align, theorems, formulas

I have checked the other questions related to this topic, however I haven't gotten any smarter in my case. The error still seems to appear even though I've tried around to get it to work.

I have this align statement inside a theorem, which seems to break the whole text:

```
\begin{satz}
Es sei $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ (der goldene Schnitt) und $\psi = \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Dann gilt
\begin{align*}
$\forall n\in\math bb{N}\text{:}\quad F_n &= \frac{\phi^{n}-\psi^{n}}{sqrt{5}}\text{.}$
\end{align*}
\end{satz}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Dollars inside `align*` are the source of errors.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke thank you very much, that fixed it!

Comment: Addendum: the reason why it's an error is that `align` already places you in math mode, so you mustn't put dollar signs around math if you're already in an `align` environment.

Comment: @bonk that's good to know for the future, thank you!

Comment: `\math bb` is also an error, you presumably intended `\mathbb`

Answer (score 0):

Answered by others, must wait 2 days before accepting.

Dollars inside align* are the source of errors. –
Przemysław Scherwentke

Addendum: the reason why it's an error is that align already places you in math mode, so you mustn't put dollar signs around math if you're already in an align environment. –
bonk

Comment: apart from that you should not use align for one-line displays where there is necessarily no alignment

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and what if it should be aligned? My exercise is to mimic a .pdf from our university and in that it is centered

Comment: align is for aligning a symbol such as = on one line with usually another = on the next line. if you only have one line there is nothing useful it can do and it has worse vertical space than `\[...\]` for a simple displayed equation. use `\[a=b\]` for a centred equation